# Check if a Function is Differentiable at a Point

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives

> Let 
>   $$f(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> x+1 & x\leq0 \\
> 3^{-x} & x>0
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Is the function differentiable at $x=0$?

I should look at the limits $$\lim_{h\to 0-} \frac{x+h+1-(x+1)}{h}$$

and $$\lim_{h\to 0+} \frac{3^{-(x+h)}-3^{-x}}{h}$$

What would I do if the point was for example $x=3$?

Answer (score 3):

HINT:  in general a function say $y=f(x)$ is said to be differentiable at any point $x=a$ iff $$\text{left hand derivative}=\text{right hand derivative}$$  $$\lim_{h\to 0^- }\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+ }\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$
or $$\lim_{h\to 0 }\frac{f(a-h)-f(a)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0 }\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

Answer (score 2):

You get then

$$\lim_{h\to 3^-} \frac{3^{-(x+h)}-3^{-x}}{h}$$

$$\lim_{h\to 3^+} \frac{3^{-(x+h)}-3^{-x}}{h}$$

However, it is a known fact that $g(x)=3^{-x}$ is differentiable for all $x$ and since $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ in the neighbourhood of 3, you can also say that $f$ is differentiable for $x=3$.

---

There is however a reason why $x=0$ is interesting specifically. At $x=0$, two completely different functions meet and form one function. This sometimes causes that the function is not differentiable, or not even continuous.

Comment: I wanted to know if I take $h$ to the wanted point or plug in the point in the x variable and take $h$ to 0

Comment: @gbox A clarification might help us: if you were to take $h$ to the desired point (for example, to test differentiability at $3$, taking $h\to 3$), what do you think $x$ would be?

Answer (score 1):

Plug in the value (0 or 3) into whatever you got in evaluating those limits.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly apply the definition of derivative by replacing $x$ with $3$.

The meaning of using $x$ is to convey that you can find the derivative at any general point!

To find the right derivative you can use L'Hopitals rule and see whether the the left and right hand derivatives are equal and then say whether the derivative exist or not.

Answer (score 1):

Notice:

- $$\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{x+h+1-(x+1)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{x+h+1-x-1}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}1=1$$
- $$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{3^{-(x+h)}-3^{-x}}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{3^{-h-x}-3^{-x}}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{3^{-h-x}\left(1-3^h\right)}{3^{-h-x}\left(3^{h+x}h\right)}=$$
  $$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{3^{-h-x}\left(1-3^h\right)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}h}\left(3^{-h-x}\left(1-3^h\right)\right)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}h}\left(h\right)}=\lim_{h\to0^+}-\frac{\ln(3)3^{-x}}{\ln(3)h+1}=$$
  $$-\frac{\ln(3)3^{-x}}{\ln(3)\cdot0+1}=-\ln(3)3^{-x}=-\frac{\ln(3)}{3^x}$$

Comment: but I plug in for example 0.01 so I get -\$frac{ln(3)}{x^{0.01}} \eqiv 1$

Comment: What have you done in the in the third step of the limit of $3^x$?

Comment: @gbox, Yes if you set $x=\frac{1}{100}$ than your limit is equal to $-\frac{\ln(3)}{\sqrt[100]{3}}$. And in the third step I've multiplied the numerator with $1-3^h$ and the denominator with $3^{h+x}h$